# What is the encryption algorithm used here?

Tags: cipher, algorithm

Can you decipher what encryption algorithm has been used here. I have several examples but I cannot decipher the algorithm used.

```
076a720f-67e6-4dd9-b9f2-38464e10d6ac = 35246
d1265cd3-cc3c-46d1-b1b2-a3f31ad5c094 = 36208
be7a8fb3-9799-47fd-b0c3-329fdc97d980 = 36312
6b4bc26c-89cb-43be-8d94-87ddf9e852d4 = 36378
8e3bc655-e419-41be-b9c3-42e999dc7a0f = 36425
```

What would be the encrypted value of the number 1500 be, using this algorithm?

Comment: Just to be clear, do you actually know the answer to this puzzle or not?

Comment: no, i do not know the answer

Comment: These appear to be [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)'s. I think you might be more successful on one of the more IT-centric stackexchange sites when you provide more context about where this data comes from.

Comment: The answer about how to identify UUID's is likely helpful but this question turns out to be "not a puzzle".  As such, I am voting to close as off-topic.

Answer (score 4):

These are Version 4 [Universally Unique Identifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier). You can tell that they are UUID's because they are hexadecimal strings in the characteristic pattern of `xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx`. You can tell they are Version 4 by the digit `4` as the first digit of the third group.

Unfortunately the Version 4 of UUID's is completely randomly generated. Whatever system generates these numbers likely checks if that number is already in its database, and when it isn't it generates a randomly generated new UUID for it.

Comment: thanks a lot, one question: may one number have different UUID  encrypted value?

Comment: UUID have nothing to do with encryption. As Philip said, they are randomly generated for each of your number, no special algorithm is present. So yes, they can have different value for the same number, depending on how your system handle them.